# Error 403 while trying to build against Fabric.io

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

While trying to rebuild my project, I got the following Gradle error:

> Error:Could not GET
>   'https://maven.fabric.io/repo/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync
>   project

Anyone stumbled upon this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fabric are being Fabric again.
They've changed the repo URL to: https://maven.fabric.io/public

So I went and did a find-and-replace on all of my gradle files. Now the project compiles fine.

The "official" answer is here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-build-with-fabric/63903

Comment: Thanks fro the bounty. I'm humbled